# cross module variable

Tags: python, import, module

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142545/python-how-to-make-a-cross-module-variable) I got an idea about how using variables from other modules. this all works fine with

```
import foo as bar
```

But I don't want to import my modules as "bar" I want to use it without any prefix like

```
from foo import *
```

Using this it´s impossible to modify variables from other modules. reading will work! any idea? suggestions?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/global-variable-and-python

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281184/why-cant-i-set-a-global-variable-in-python

Comment: What does "it´s impossible to modify variables from other modules" mean?  Are you trying to update the other module's source file on disk?  Are you simply trying to access a module global variable?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to import a value *from* a module and have it readable and writable by the importing scope. When you just `import foo` in Python, it creates a module object named `foo`. Getting and setting attributes on a module object will change them in the module's scope. But when you `from foo import something`, `foo` is imported and a module object is created, but is not returned. Instead, Python copies the values you specified out of `foo` and puts them in the local scope. If what you are importing is an immutable type like `int` or `str`, then changing it and having the changes reflect in the `foo` module is impossible. It's similar to this:

```
>>> class N(object):
...   def __init__(self, value):
...     self.value = value
>>> n = N(3)
>>> value = n.value
>>> print value, n.value
3 3
>>> value = 4
>>> print value, n.value
4 3
```

Excepting crude hacks, if you really want to be able to modify the module's variable, you will need to import the module itself and modify the variable on the module. But generally, having to do this is indicative of bad design. If you are the writer of the `foo` module in question, you may want to look at some other, more Pythonic ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, it's impossible, and you'll have to use a prefix.

It's important to understand that `from foo import x, y` is *copying* `x` to your namespace.  It's equivallent to:

```
import foo
# COPY TO YOUR NAMESPACE
x = foo.x
y = foo.y
# `from foo import` does NOT leave `foo` in your namespace
def foo
```

This way, each module will get a local copy of `x` and `y`.  Changing `x` won't be seen in other modules, and you won't see changes other modules do :-(

To change the central copy of a variable you must import the module itself: `import foo` and change `foo.x`.  This way only one copy exists and everybody is accessing it :-)

[The linked questions also mention the possibility to put the shared variable in the module **builtin**.  DON'T!  This would eliminate the prefix for reading it, but not for writing, and is extremely bad style.]

### A note in defense of Python

If you resent the need to use a `foo.` prefix here, you'll probably also resent the need for the `self.` prefix to access object variables.  The bottom line is that's how Python works - since you don't declare variables, there is no choice but to use prefixes.

But there is also an upside: when reading Python code, you easily see where each variable lives.  IMHO that's very good.

Supporting evidence: in other languages like C++/Java, many people observe conventions like an `m_` prefix on all object variable names to achieve a similar effect...

### Style remarks

1. You don't need `import foo as bar`, just use `import foo`.
   The `as` form doesn't do anything new, it just renames it, which is just confusing.
   It's only useful if "foo" is a very long name; a particularly accepted case is when "foo" lives deep in some package, so you can do `import long.package.foo as foo`.
2. The `from foo import *` is considered very bad style in programs because:

   - The person reading your code won't know where names came from.
   - It pollutes your namespace, which can lead to subtle bugs when names from 
     different modules clash.

   The explicit form `from foo import x, y` is OK, but starts suffering from the same problems if you use many names from the module.
   In such cases, it's best to `import foo` and explicitly write `foo.x`, `foo.y`.

Bottom line: when in doubt, a simple `import foo` is best.

Exception: It *is* very handy to use `import *` when experimenting at the interactive interpreter.  Note however that it doesn't play well with `reload()`, so don't use it when debugging changing code.  (To debug a module you are writing, it's best to launch a fresh interpreter *inside* the module's namespace - `python -i mymodule.py` / F5 in IDLE.)

Answer (score 0):

By using `import foo from bar` you don't import `bar` as a variable but as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

`from foo import *` is frowned upon (by me, by [Google's style guide](http://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide#Module_and_package_imports), by the [OLPC style guide](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Python_Style_Guide#Imports) - which you should see, as it has the best explanations of why this is bad - but not by [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), unfortunately). - it makes for unreadable code.

Consider:

```
from foo import *
from bar import *
from baz import *

dostuff()
```

If you have an error running `dostuff()`, where do you look for the problem? It could have come from any of those imports.

For readable, maintainable code, stick with `from foo import bar`. For readable, modular, maintainable code, don't hack with globals - extend `bar` (by subclassing, if you can't change the upstream source) to expose methods for modifying the values you need to access.