# Why does python think this is a local variable?

Tags: python

I have a global variable I called Y_VAL which is initialized to a value of 2.

I then have a function, called f() (for brevity), which uses Y_VAL.

```
def f():
    y = Y_VAL
    Y_VAL += 2
```

However, when trying to run my code, python gives the error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Y_VAL' referenced before assignment
```

If I remove the last line `Y_VAL += 2` it works fine.

Why does python think that Y_VAL is a local variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I set a global variable in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281184/why-cant-i-set-a-global-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing the line `global Y_VAL` inside the function.

When `Y_VAL` occurs on the right-hand-side of an assignment, it's no problem because the local scope is searched first, then the global scope is searched.  However, on the left-hand-side, you can only *assign* to a global that way when you've explicitly declared `global Y_VAL`.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt):

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

Comment: Does this behavior apply differently for dicts? I found that I can declare a global dict and then assign to it inside a function without using `global`... might you know the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems like I have the same question as VMDX. Given a global dictionary 'd', I have been able to add/change it without using the keyword global. How come this is the case? same with lists

Comment: You can change the contents *inside* the list or dict. You can't change (rebind) the reference to the list/dict. So `d[2:]= 3` is OK, but `d+= [3]` is not.

Comment: The difference has nothing to do with dicts at all.  You are simply comparing two completely different operations: "Assignment to a name" and "assignment to an item of an object bound to a name".

`foo[i] = bar` performs a name lookup for `foo` in local and global namespace (in this order), and then sets the item at index `i` to `bar` (by invoking `foo.__setitem__()`).  `foo = bar` does not perform any lookup at all, but simply sets the name `foo` in the local namespace (unless `foo` as been declared global or nonlocal).

Answer (score 2):

This is just how Python works:  Assignment always binds the left-hand side name in the closest surrounding name space.  Inside of a function the closest namespace is the local namespace of the function.

In order to assign to a global variable, you have to declare it `global`.  But avoid `global` by all means.  Global variables are almost always bad design, and thus the use of the `global` keyword is a strong hint, that you are making design mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran to the same issue as you  and as many others like you, before realising it needs the global statement. I then decided to move everything to object orientation and have piece of mind. Call me insane but I just dont trust myself with the global statement and its not difficult to come against a problem of local scope that is a pain to debug.

So I would advice collect all your "global" variables put them in a class inside an **init**(self) and not only you wont have to worry about local scope but you will have your code much better organised. Its not a freak of luck that most programmer out there prefer OOP.