# if g == 0: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables

I have hosted a multiplayer game which runs on python, and i wanted to edit the script in such a way that when i join a message showing that i am playing is displayed on everyone's screen. i was able to do this but the message is shown in the start of every match, i tried to fix it but i'm getting a problem.
This is the python script i'm trying to edit:

```
def onPlayerJoin(self,player):
    'Called for all new bs.Players (including the initial set of them).'
    if player.getName(full=True,icon=False) == "AwesomeLogic":
        if g == 0:
            bs.screenMessage("AwesomeLogic is playing")
            g = 1


def onPlayerLeave(self,player):
    'Called when a player is leaving the activity.'
    g = 0
```

But this gives me an error:

```
 if g == 0: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'g' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have to define ```g``` as global variable else it assumes it as the local variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I set a global variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281184/why-cant-i-set-a-global-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about variable scope: all variables (re)assigned within a function are considered local by default. This is the case for your `g`, thus `g` is considered local and not defined yet at `if g == 0:`.

You can use `global g` to define `g` as a global variable within your function, although use of global variables is strongly discouraged...

Comment: just add `global g` first thing in your function