# Adding to a Variable in a Loop. Variable keeps resetting to 0

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm working on a small trivia game that adds 5 points for every question you get right. I have a function that has a loop where it asks you a question. If the answer is right then it adds 5 points and prints your score along with a message and then loops back to ask you a question. Otherwise it prints the correct answer and gives you a final score.

My problem is that the way I am making my loop the value of PlayerPoints is getting set to 0  every time the loop restarts. So while the points are being added the PlayerPoints value is being equaled to 0 every iteration.

Here is my code:

```
from random import randrange
WDCs = ((2023, "Max Verstappen"), (2022, "Max Verstappen"),
        (2021, "Max Verstappen"), (2020, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2019, "Lewis Hamilton"), (2018, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2017, "Lewis Hamilton"), (2016, "Nico Rosberg"),
        (2015, "Lewis Hamilton"), (2014, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2013, "Sebastian Vettel"), (2012, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2011, "Sebastian Vettel"), (2010, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2009, "Jenson Button"), (2008, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2007, "Kimi Raikkonen"), (2006, "Fernando Alonso"),
        (2005, "Fernando Alonso"), (2004, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (2003, "Michael Schumacher"), (2002, "Michael Schimacher"),
        (2001, "Michael Schumacher"), (2000, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (1999, "Mike Hakkinen"), (1998, "Mika Hakkinen"),
        (1997, "Jaques Villeneuve"), (1996, "Damon Hill"),
        (1995, "Michael Schumacher"), (1994, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (1993, "Alain Prost"), (1992, "Nigel Mansell"),
        (1991, "Ayrton Senna"), (1990, "Ayrton Senna"),
        (1989, "Alain Prost"), (1988, "Ayrton Senna"),
        (1987, "Nelson Piquet"), (1986, "Alain Prost"),
        (1986, "Alain Prost"), (1985, "Alain Prost"),
        (1984, "Niki Lauda"), (1983, "Nelson Piquet"),
        (1982, "Keke Rosberg"), (1981, "Nelson Piquet"),
        (1980, "Alan Jones"), (1979, "Jody Scheckter"),
        (1978, "Mario Andretti"), (1977, "Niki Lauda"),
        (1976, "James Hunt"), (1975, "Niki Lauda"),
        (1974, "Emerson Fittipaldi"), (1973, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1972, "Emerson Fittipaldi"), (1971, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1970, "Jochen Rindt"), (1969, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1968, "Graham Hill"), (1967, "Denny Hulme"),
        (1966, "Jack Brabham"), (1965, "Jim Clark"),
        (1964, "John Surtees"), (1963, "Jim Clark"),
        (1962, "Graham Hill"), (1961, "Phil hill"),
        (1960, "Jack Brabham"), (1959, "Jack Brabham"),
        (1958, "Jack Hawthorn"), (1957, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1956, "Juan Manuel Fangio"), (1955, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1954, "Juan Manuel Fangio"), (1953, "Alberto Ascari"),
        (1952, "ALberto Ascari"), (1951, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1950, "Giusepe Farina")
        )

def questionmaker():
    PlayerPoints = 0
    LocalWDC = ((WDCs[randrange(73)]))
    print(f"Who won the World Championship in {LocalWDC[0]}? ")
    PlayerResponse = input(str())
    if PlayerResponse == LocalWDC[1]:
        PlayerPoints = PlayerPoints + 5
        print("That's Correct!")
        print(f"Your score is {PlayerPoints}!")
        return questionmaker()
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The Champion that year was {LocalWDC[1]}.")
        print(f"Your Final Score is {PlayerPoints}!")

questionmaker()
```

It's probably something very simple but I'm stumped and can't figure out how to do it properly. I've tried doing a nested function and using a while loop to no results.

I know python doesn't support the goto function so I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Every time you call `questionmaker()` you assign `PlayerPoints = 0` as the first step. How do you expect to add to the old value?

Comment: Don't use recursion. Use a `while` loop. Initialize the score before the loop, and add to it inside the loop.

Comment: If you really want to use recursion for some reason, pass `PlayerPoints` as a parameter.

Comment: I have no idea. I have tried adding the variable inside the if loop and outside the function but it returns an error saying "UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'PlayerPoints' where it is not associated with a value"

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281184/why-cant-i-set-a-global-variable-in-python

Comment: How is the "player" supposed to terminate the "game"?

Comment: Still working on that but I'll probably just add something along the lines of typing "Save Game" saves the score and ends the game. This function is just a part of a larger project. I felt it wasn't overly relevant to post all the code.

Comment: There is no loop in your function. Recursion is not a loop. An if statement is not a loop.

Comment: @pho Recursion is sort-of, kind-of, a loop; it's just not a syntactic loop construct.

Comment: @chepner and Python has no tail-call optimization, so you can't make wildly liberal use of it.

Comment: @Chris Unless you write your own trampoline and trampoline-compatible code :) (I kid; the trampoline itself is a while loop, and the trampoline-compatible code just adds a bunch of function-call overhead to the trampoline's iteration.)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using recursion, you need to accumulate points somewhere. A local variable's value is unique to the function call currently happening. Global variables could work, but *don't go down that road*.

So the answer is to use a function argument to convey that information from one function call to the next.

```
def questionmaker(PlayerPoints=0):
    LocalWDC = ((WDCs[randrange(73)]))
    print(f"Who won the World Championship in {LocalWDC[0]}? ")
    PlayerResponse = input(str())
    if PlayerResponse == LocalWDC[1]:
        PlayerPoints += 5
        print("That's Correct!")
        print(f"Your score is {PlayerPoints}!")
        return questionmaker(PlayerPoints)
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The Champion that year was {LocalWDC[1]}.")
        print(f"Your Final Score is {PlayerPoints}!")
```

Better would be to use an explicit loop rather than recursion.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop. Recursion is not appropriate.

You can also simplify the (pseudo)random selection of the question by utilising the *choice()* function from the *random* module.

A simple technique for breaking the loop would be to test for empty input - i.e., player just hits Return and the *input()* function will then return an empty string.

```
from random import choice

WDCs = ((2023, "Max Verstappen"), 
        (2022, "Max Verstappen"),
        (2021, "Max Verstappen"),
        (2020, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2019, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2018, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2017, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2016, "Nico Rosberg"),
        (2015, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2014, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2013, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2012, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2011, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2010, "Sebastian Vettel"),
        (2009, "Jenson Button"),
        (2008, "Lewis Hamilton"),
        (2007, "Kimi Raikkonen"),
        (2006, "Fernando Alonso"),
        (2005, "Fernando Alonso"),
        (2004, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (2003, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (2002, "Michael Schimacher"),
        (2001, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (2000, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (1999, "Mike Hakkinen"),
        (1998, "Mika Hakkinen"),
        (1997, "Jaques Villeneuve"),
        (1996, "Damon Hill"),
        (1995, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (1994, "Michael Schumacher"),
        (1993, "Alain Prost"),
        (1992, "Nigel Mansell"),
        (1991, "Ayrton Senna"),
        (1990, "Ayrton Senna"),
        (1989, "Alain Prost"),
        (1988, "Ayrton Senna"),
        (1987, "Nelson Piquet"),
        (1986, "Alain Prost"),
        (1986, "Alain Prost"),
        (1985, "Alain Prost"),
        (1984, "Niki Lauda"),
        (1983, "Nelson Piquet"),
        (1982, "Keke Rosberg"),
        (1981, "Nelson Piquet"),
        (1980, "Alan Jones"),
        (1979, "Jody Scheckter"),
        (1978, "Mario Andretti"),
        (1977, "Niki Lauda"),
        (1976, "James Hunt"),
        (1975, "Niki Lauda"),
        (1974, "Emerson Fittipaldi"),
        (1973, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1972, "Emerson Fittipaldi"),
        (1971, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1970, "Jochen Rindt"),
        (1969, "Jackie Stewart"),
        (1968, "Graham Hill"),
        (1967, "Denny Hulme"),
        (1966, "Jack Brabham"),
        (1965, "Jim Clark"),
        (1964, "John Surtees"),
        (1963, "Jim Clark"),
        (1962, "Graham Hill"),
        (1961, "Phil Hill"),
        (1960, "Jack Brabham"),
        (1959, "Jack Brabham"),
        (1958, "Jack Hawthorn"),
        (1957, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1956, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1955, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1954, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1953, "Alberto Ascari"),
        (1952, "ALberto Ascari"),
        (1951, "Juan Manuel Fangio"),
        (1950, "Giusepe Farina")
        )

def questionmaker():
    score = 0
    while True:
        year, driver = choice(WDCs)
        answer = input(f"Who won the world championship in {year}? ")
        if answer:
            if answer == driver:
                print("That's correct")
                score += 5
            else:
                print(f"Wrong! The champion that year was {driver}")
            print(f"Your current score is {score}")
        else:
            break # empty input breaks the loop
    print(f"Your final score is {score}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    questionmaker()
```

**Note:**

A better (and more concise) way of managing the drivers and their winning years would be to use a dictionary keyed on driver name with each driver's value being a sequence of years (list or tuple). You would then need to make 2 random selections. Driver first then a year from his value. That also solves the problem of typos (as you have in your code) for the driver names although you could consider normalising to upper/lower case